# System function in RStudio won't speak, stop sign won't go away

Tags: r, macos, system

I can't run this code on my Mac laptop, but my coworkers can run it on their machines.

```
system("say Done Processing")
```

This is inside of a shared function we are using, and every time I run the function it will get to that point in the function and freeze. The stop sign will not go away, and I have to terminate the R session in order to continue using R. It's the same result if I just run that single line.

Am I missing a file on my computer that allows this system function to work?

Comment: Stop sign? R doesn't have any "stop signs".

Comment: It works on my Mac. You could add `wait = FALSE` to send the command and let R move on, but that won't actually make it run. Can you run anything with `system`? There's a lot of ways it could go wrong...

Comment: The `say` verb sounds more like an "AppleScript" or some such OSX-specific operation.

Comment: Go to a Terminal session. Type: `say Done Processing`<return>`

Comment: It used to work on my mac, but I'm not sure what I did to change it. I think a file might be missing, I get this error when I try to run it in R instead of RStudio. Anyone know how to fix this?     system("say hello")
Warning message:
In system("say hello") : system call failed: No such file or directory

Comment: I tried typing that in the terminal session and nothing happened